# What are the options for deploying a commercial desktop .NET application?

Tags: .net, deployment, installation

There must be many other developers looking for a "good" method of deploying a [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) desktop application, where "good" means:

- Ease of installation for a trial user
- Reasonable download size (Not a 350 MB monstrosity)
- Low cost of any purchased tool
- Targets Windows XP SP3, Windows Vista, Windows 7, etc.

If a user has to jump through too many hoops, or the download takes too long, the user won't try the software and will never find out how great/useful it is. So this is the major consideration.

Other relevant factors:

- Development environment: Visual Studio 2010 or 2008 (can switch)
- Installation requirements are simple: nothing Visual Studio Installer can't handle.
- Learning curve: a walk-through of a similar .NET deployment is highly desirable.
- Although currently targeting .NET 2.0, targeting a later version of .NET (4.0 client profile?) without reboots (Windows Installer 3.1 install!) might be useful/desirable.

As far as I can tell, all pure Microsoft approaches involve multiple files making for complex installation instructions (download X, Y, run X, tidy up).

Comment: A Setup project does all this.  Sounds to me you haven't even tried it.

Comment: @Hans - Sounds to me like you haven't tried installing .Net on "bare" Windows systems:-). Then look at (a) how much explanation was required for the user, and (b) the support cost when users screw up the installation. A setup project produces a setup.exe file and a .msi file. If you just use the .msi file the .net prerequisite install isn't automatic. If Windows Installer 3.1 is not pre-installed it's even more problematic.

Comment: Well, send them the exe, not the msi.  MSI 3.1 is one of the baked-in included prerequisites for any setup project.  Complaining that users get it wrong doesn't help us help you unless you can give concrete examples of how they got it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember the exact mechanics, but you can set your installer to download the .NET framework directly from Microsoft, rather than your own site, and only if it's not already installed.

Additionally, look into targeting the Client Profile, which is "only" 50 MB (still large, but better than 350 MB). Finally, Windows Vista and Windows 7 ship with .NET pre-installed, and Microsoft is using it in some of their own software, so penetration of the framework is actually pretty high. It's much rarer these days for a user to need to install the framework along with your application, at least as long as you stick with 2.0 or 3.5.

Comment: .NET4 (if it's an option - it does run on your targets :-) has much better distribution "sizes" (client *and* full): http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TowardsASmallerNET4DetailsOnTheClientProfileAndDownloadingNET.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately the exact mechanics are important and the reason I'm asking this question. The automatic download from Microsoft would be OK if I could use a single executable. Currently I'm sticking to 2.0 precisely because it's more likely to be pre-installed. But one day I'd like the option of using a later version...

Comment: @MZB you can zip the setup.exe file and the setup.msi file together in a self-extracting exe for distribution.

Answer (score 0):

If Windows Installer 3.1 or later and .NET framework is present in the target machine, creating an installer using Setup projects was a pretty straightforward experience for me.

The result is a single [MSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) file to download and run. You just add the project output to the setup project and you are good to go.

If you stick to .NET 2.0, I believe it was smaller than .NET 3.5 SP1.

Another alternative is [XCOPY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XCOPY_deployment). You compress the bin folder of the application and ask the user uncompress and run the application.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The "If Windows Installer 3.1 and .Net framework is present" is precisely the reason I'm asking. I can't assume it is unless I remove XP/.Net 3.x as targets. (XCopy isn't suitable for commercial deployment).